# Programs missing from Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I downloaded Kali Linux mini for 32 bit from the official website onto Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop that originally had Ubuntu.

It didn't load GRUB and was told I can skip this step. I attempted this several times.

Now I managed to log into Kali Linux (it didn't recognize username and password I set during install so I tried root along with password I set)

Now there are many programs missing from Kali, including whole "Password" section.

Other than reinstalling or attempting to download the full 3GB iso again is there a simple fix to get all the programs?

Comment: unfortunately, we are not tech support

Comment: @schroeder, fortunately :)

Comment: @schroeder so it's one of those quirks with installing software then ... ok, thanks!

Comment: @RomeoNinov I thought members of this forum would be familiar with Kali, and could advise .... Peace!

Comment: @SohniMahiwal, man apt-get

Comment: This site is for security, people are a little bit distasteful to you because your question is a kali linux problem, and not security related. On http://unix.stackexchange.com you will get a more friendly treatment.

Comment: @peterh This question was originally posted on SuperUser, it was migrated to security. Many courses in security require students to use Kali Linux to learn pen-testing, and protect THEMSELVES from malicious users.  But if anyone wishes to be unfriendly its their choice. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install missing programs by running "apt-get install kali-linux-all"
to install the missing programs. You can also install a desktop by running "apt-get install kali-desktop-gnome"